# Qtimer Bloking Slots Value

Tags: qt, qtimer

Hi I have a bellowing code. I want to add some delay (6second) for appering QMesaageBox. But in background reading 2 ports. I dont want to delay block port value.

```
  motorStart();

QString msv = "msv?0;";
loadcellPort->write(msv.toStdString().c_str(),msv.length());

plotFlag = true;
newPlot = true;

ui->startButton->setEnabled(false);
ui->cancelButton->setEnabled(false);

QTimer::singleShot(5000,this,SLOT(onSerialLoadcellData()));

QMessageBox::information(this,"Bastak Test",json_map["QWater"].toString(),json_map["QFinishAccept"].toString());
```

I was use QThread before and this thread bloking port value ?

```
class Sleeper : public QThread
{
 public:
static void msleep(unsigned long msecs){QThread::msleep(msecs);}

 };
```

Comment: And I dont find any method for insede to SLOT().

Comment: where are you calling `sleep`? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: I was use before. I replace with QTimer::singleShot .... line

Comment: like Sleeper::msleep(5000);

Comment: Sorry I'm still not sure what your question is now. `Sleeper::msleep(5000);` will block the thread for 5 seconds, but `QTimer::singleShot` will **not** block the thread and return immediately and call the slot in 5 seconds.

Comment: I wrote single shot code but it's not working. Question is this.